# Get UserInfo from Wordpress

Tags: users, rest-api, user-meta, endpoints

I am building a website and trying to pull the data from Wordpress using the WP rest api. On wordpress, the WooCommerce plugin has been added so the user contain more info and I have added additional field using a plugin.

First, how can I get all the user info ? incl. WooCommerce (mostly billing/Shipping) and also all the tother fields I have added using `CIMY user extrafield`. I am coding in react but I do not really care about the react part.

I am more interested to understand, who WP handle it (endpoint) and a simple example with Postman is enough.

I tried `http://xx.yyy.zzz.aaa/wp-json/wp/v2/users/user_id` and add the authorization token in the header but it's not working. it keep replying:

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you replace `user_id` with the user's ID?

Comment: Yes I did. I just used user_id as example. For example one login is `amartin` so I replaced user_id by `amartin`

Comment: That's not the user ID. That's a username. The user ID is a number. You can see it when retrieving users via the API, or looking in the URL when editing a user in WordPress.

Comment: @JacobPeattie how do i get this ID ? I thought that the jwt token may have it.

Comment: How are you authenticating the user? [This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/) plugin shows that the ID is returned on a successful auth, for example. So check the response of the auth request.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a JWT for the current user (that is logged into WordPress), you can use this endpoint:

`/wp/v2/users/me`

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#retrieve-a-user-2

You can also check the token to see what claims are available at https://jwt.ms